# Is there a command that works for command line arguments like the sort command does for files?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I am trying to write a script in BASH that will take between 1 and 5 command line arguments from the user and report them back in reverse numerical order to standard output. The only command I know that would work similarly to this is the sort command, but this only works for files. Is there a similar command for sorting command line arguments? Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ] || [ $# -gt 5 ];
then echo "Incorrect number of arguments!"
else
     sorted=sort -rn $*
     echo "SORTED: $sorted"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
sorted=$( printf '%s\n' "$@" | sort -rn )
printf '%s\n' "${sorted//$'\n'/ }"
```

Comment: +1. using printf like this is the safest, most concise way to output a list of things one per line. For outputting them as a single line, I'd be tempted to ignore my own commendations and just `echo $sorted` (without any quotes) -- or `sorted=( $(print ...|sort) ); printf "%s " "${sorted[@]}"`

Comment: Thanks! Or: `sorted=($(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort -nr)); printf '%s\n' "${sorted[*]}"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `sort` command values from standard input.  It expects every value on its own line, which you can achieve by combining `echo` and `tr`:

```
sorted=$(echo $* | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -rn - | tr '\n' ' ')
```

The last invocation of `tr` is only necessary if you want the result to be space-delimited again and not newline-delimited.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ] || [ $# -gt 5 ];
then echo "Incorrect number of arguments!"
else
     sorted=$(echo $* | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -rn | tr '\n' ' ')
     echo "SORTED: $sorted"
fi
echo $* | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -rn | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use command substitution `$(...)` to capture the output of a command like that.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ] || [ $# -gt 5 ]; then
    echo "Incorrect number of arguments!"
else
    sorted=$(for var in "$@"; do echo "$var"; done | sort -rn | tr -d '\n')
    echo "SORTED: $sorted"
fi

$ ./test 1 2 3 4 5
SORTED: 5 4 3 2 1
$ ./test 5 4 3 2 1
SORTED: 5 4 3 2 1
```